# Why do we think that the energy density of false vacuum/scalar field doesn’t dilute with the expansion?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, big-bang, cosmological-inflation, cosmological-constant

I have a question about inflation theory.

Why do we think that the energy density of false vacuum/scalar field doesn’t dilute with the expansion?

Could it be that the energy density does dilute with the expansion?

Is it the nature of a scalar field to maintain its energy density even with the expansion? *or* Do we think that energy density doesn’t dilute with the expansion so that it will have negative pressure which cause expansion?

Comment: related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/338664/85745

Comment: energy density (almost) doesn't dilute BECAUSE it has negative pressure. Look at the equations. A scalar field can have negative pressure if its potential energy dominates over kinetic energy for some period of time

Answer (score 1):

The energy density does dilute during inflation: it has to, or else inflation would never end.  The energy density is given by $$\rho = \frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}^2+ V(\phi)$$ where $V(\phi)$ is some potential energy function.  As long as $V(\phi)$ is not strictly constant, the inflaton field will evolve according to $$\dot{\rho} = \dot{\phi}\,(\ddot{\phi} + V'(\phi)).$$  If the total energy of the inflaton was conserved, then indeed we'd have $\dot{\rho} = 0$, but if we look at the Klein-Gordon equation for a scalar field in the Friedmann-Robertson-Walker background, $$\ddot{\phi} - 3H\dot{\phi} + V'(\phi) = 0,$$ we see that there is a *drag* term, proportional to the Hubble parameter, $3H\dot{\phi}$, that draws energy out of the inflaton as it evolves in its potential.

We therefore have $\dot{\rho} = -3H\dot{\phi}^2$, which is nonzero (and negative) as long as $\phi$ is evolving.

EDIT: I should add that the universe can still accelerate even if $\dot{\rho} \neq 0$.  To see this, note that $\ddot{a} = a(\dot{H} + H^2) > 0$ which leads to the following bound,
$$\frac{|\dot{H}|}{H^2} < 1.$$

In words, the universe will accelerate if it is vacuum dominated and the field isn't evolving too quickly relative to the expansion rate.